# Why are my progress bars displaying incorrectly in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, progress-bar

I'm getting strange behavior from my HTML5 progress bars in IE (10) and wonder if there's anything I can do to [my CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Aldaron/PzrLu/) to fix it.

I have some simple HTML `progress` elements

```
<progress max="100" value="10"></progress><br/>
<progress max="100" value="30"></progress><br/>
<progress max="100" value="50"></progress><br/>
<progress max="100" value="70"></progress><br/>
<progress max="100" value="90"></progress><br/>
<progress max="100" value="100"></progress>
```

That I've styled [using CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Aldaron/PzrLu/) that I've adapted from various sources which ought to work on "all browsers".

On all browsers other than IE, I get what I expect:

[image]

But on IE, a black line is added at the end of each bar, and the 100% bar does not display the correct color:

[image]

Is there something I can change in [my CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Aldaron/PzrLu/) to get the IE progress bars to display correctly in IE?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`::-ms-fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) pseudo element:

```
progress::-ms-fill {
    border: none;
}

progress[value="100"]::-ms-fill {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PzrLu/13/

Comment: Is that the pseudo-element I should use throughout for IE — i.e., should I use it whatever I have `-webkit-progress-value`?

Comment: Yes - this only controls the determinate part of the progress bar (like `::-webkit-progress-value`).

Comment: And it's `background-color` not color? In other words: it's just like Webkit/Moz, but substituting `-ms-fill` everywhere I have `-webkit-progress-value`/`-moz-progress-bar`? (The examples I was working from had different advice for handling IE.)

Comment: I can't say whether to use `background-color` or `color` (as they both work) but I would say yes, you should include `::-ms-fill` wherever you're using `::-webkit-progress-value` and `::-moz-progress-bar`.

Comment: It's only supported in IE10/11.

Comment: Any idea what these will look like in IE < 10 (I don't have a way of testing)?

Comment: It unfortunately won't show up at all in < IE 10. If you're desperate to make this work in older versions of IE, there is a nice [polyfill](http://lea.verou.me/2011/07/a-polyfill-for-html5-progress-element-the-obsessive-perfectionist-way/) available from Lea Verou.

Comment: If it won't show up at all, thats fine. I don't care about old IE, just as long as it doesn't produce a mess.